# How can I find least squares intersection of 3D rays?

Tags: geometry, regions, intersection

I'm using version 11 for whatever that's worth. I'm doing an optical simulation with thousands of converging rays (`HalfLine`s), since this is in 3D for the most part they don't intersect, but I would like to find the closest point among all of the rays. I'm new to *Mathematica* so I'm trying to figure out what an efficient and idiomatic way to do this is. The docs have a nice example with two regions like this:

```
{d, pqrul} = Minimize[EuclideanDistance[p, q], {p ∈ , q ∈  // RootReduce
```

I've thought of trying to adapt that somehow (all pairs of points in the `RegionUnion` of the lines?) but that seems grossly inefficient. There's always the [MATLAB way](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37192-intersection-point-of-lines-in-3d-space/content/lineIntersect3D.m). Still, I'd like to learn the idiomatic way because I'd also like to be able to visualize these things without packing them into and stripping them out of matrices.

Comment: Have you seen `RegionDistance[]` and `RegionNearest[]`?

Comment: I already wrote an answer, but became unsure afterwards: do you want your solution to be on some of the `HalfLines`, or just the least squares solution to the problem, anywhere in space?

Comment: It can be anywhere in space, your answer looks great! Thanks!

Comment: Do you need `HalfLine`s, or would `InfiniteLine`s work, too? That would simplify the problem a lot. I ask because the "Matlab way", as far as I can see, assumes infinite lines.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT**: As @nikie noted, using `FindArgMin` (a variant of `FindMinimum`) instead of `(N)ArgMin` can improve the speed of finding a solution. Since in the case of this problem only one minimum exists, this should actually produce the global minimum in an efficient manner.

How about this?

```
Module[{n, lines, sol},
 n = 10;
 lines = HalfLine[# + RandomPoint@Ball[], -2 # + RandomPoint@Ball[]] & /@
      RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 10], n];
 sol = 
  FindArgMin[Norm[RegionDistance[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ lines], {x, y, z}];
 Graphics3D[{Arrow@Tube@{#1, #1 + #2} & @@@ lines, 
   Red, PointSize@Large, Point@sol}]]
```

[image]

Here `lines` is a list of random almost-focused `HalfLines`, `sol` is the coordinate of least-squares solution, and rest is just visualizing the result (red `Point` marks the spot).

This solution is constrained - by the fact `HalfLine`s have a starting point, and that distances behind this point are measured to it, instead of the projection on the infinite line. This differs from solution provided by @J.M. which employs fully infinite lines. My solution can be turned into equivalent with that solution just by replacing `HalfLine` with `InfiniteLine`.

Comment: This definitely did work, thank you! I randomly sampled 500 rays and it did take quite awhile to compute, but ultimately good. If it's alright I'd like to leave it open 1 day just to see if anyone else can suggest a more efficient solution? Otherwise I'll be happy to accept this one.

Comment: Er, I'm not sure why, but it seems that replacing `ArgMin` into `{x,y,z}/.NMinimize[***][[2]]` can increase the speed for 3 times when 30 lines are presented.

Comment: @Wjx Plainly replacing `ArgMin` with `NArgMin` does that, too. Since input to `ArgMin` is already machine-precision numbers, I'm surprised by this. What's the difference here? Is there a risk `NArgMin` might miss the global minimum?

Comment: Oh, yeah yeah, I didn't see that there's no `N` before ArgMin. I suppose this sort of things won't happen? The documentation said that `NArgMin` will always try to find the global minimum.

Comment: `FindMinimum` seems much faster than `NArgMin`. It displays a warning message, but returns the same result. And if you could replace `HalfLine`s with `InfiniteLine`s, it gets much faster, but I'm not sure if that's required for the question.

Comment: @nikie Implicit reason for not choosing `FindMinimum` was that it might not find the global minimum, and it might be non-trivial to know that it's the case. I'll add a note.

Comment: @kirma: But there is only one minimum, right? `FindMinimum` is guaranteed to find *a* minimum, so if there is only one - how could `FindMinimum` not find it?

Comment: @nikie Uh-oh. I was indeed overcomplicating the problem. Indeed there's only one minimum (I must have been thinking of an another problem), and `FindMinimum` is the way to go. I'll revise my answer again!

Comment: @nikie `FindMinimum[(x^2 + x^100)/(1 + x^100), {x, 1.1}]` -- But I don't think the objective function is that sort of function in this case.

Comment: @MichaelE2: You're right, I was speaking imprecisely: The objective function here is convex (the euclidean distance from a [half-]line is convex, and the sum of convex functions is also convex). `FindMinimum` should (in theory) always find the single, global minimum for this class of objective. In practice, if you're including terms like x^100, it might not, due to numerical overflow or underflow. But you certainly could come up with equivalent examples for `NMinimize`

Comment: With the edit this handled up to 1000 rays pretty easily. Throwing 5000 at it still took longer than I cared to wait, but I'm pretty confident that a random sample of 1000 rays is plenty to get a good estimate. Interesting note for nikie, I got line search warnings for 100 rays but it went away for 500 or 1000.  Very nice, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Here's another way to implement kirma's solution:

```
With[{n = 15}, BlockRandom[SeedRandom["many lines"]; (* for reproducibility *)
     lines = HalfLine[# + RandomPoint @ Ball[], -2 # + RandomPoint @ Ball[]] & /@ 
     RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 10], n]]];

sol = LeastSquares @@ Total[
      With[{m = IdentityMatrix[3] - (Outer[Times, #, #] &[Normalize[#2]])},
           {m, m.#1}] & @@@ lines];

Graphics3D[{{Gray, Arrow[Tube[{#1, #1 + #2} & @@@ lines]]},
            {Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], Point[sol]}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: least-squares "intersection" point]

Comment: It's not really too obvious if this implementation handles `HalfLine`s as what they are defined to be, or as rays extending on both directions to the infinity. Which way it is?

Comment: @kirma, that would be the second one; as I said, I just reimplemented your solution in terms of `LeastSquares[]`. You can check that this returns the same solution as yours.

Comment: I posted an example of differing results (half-lines vs. "complete" ones) on chat ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/cx7BE.png ). Our answers are solutions to different questions. :)

Comment: Thank you for this solution also. I like how nicely it maps on to the Wikipedia notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#In_three_dimensions_2 ).